# Find all triplets in array in O(n^2)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to print all triplets in array, unlike 3SUM or anything similiar, they don't satisfy any condition. I just want to print them all.

My simple solution

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
                for (int k = j + 1; k < arr.length; k++){
                    System.out.println(arr[i] + " " + arr[j] + " " + arr[k]);
                }
            }
        }
```

runs in `O(n^3)` with the amount of triplets being `((n)*(n-1)*(n-2))/(3!)`.

So my question is, can this be done any faster than `O(n^3)`?

Comment: You cannot print O(n^3) triplets in less than O(n^3).

Comment: @DanielWagner, Never mind.  I misread the question :)

Answer (score 3):

[`n choose 3`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%20Choose%203), which is the number of combinations of triplets, is 
*`O(n^3)`*.
So no, theoretically it is impossible to do better than that since the mere operation of *printing* them will take *`O(n^3)`* operations.

Answer (score 2):

You can't print `n^3` triplets less in `n^3` operation.

If time of computing is problem you can divide your print operation in `n` threads so in theory that will reduce time by `n`.